# mysql_num_rows() error

Tags: php, html, sql

I seem to be having a rough time with this snippet of code, Which i dont understand because on my home server this works 100% perfect.  basically this script takes the users ip and stores it into a mysql table. every time a user posts it checks the table to see if the ip has already posted. when i run mysql_error() on num_rows which apears to be the problem, i get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR on line 119
```

Any ideas?

php:

```
$poster_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];//Posters ip
//check for ip double posting
//selecet ip from table
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE ip='$poster_ip'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
or die mysql_error();//line 119
//if result matche posterip, table row must be 1
if($count==1){
//ip taken
echo "This IP has already submited a post. You may not submit another.";
exit();
//else script continues
}
```

Comment: The answer given is perfect, but I would probably also try to move away from the terrible `or die` pattern. AND: it's also time for you to stop using `mysql`. It's way old and deprecated. People use PDO or mysqli these days. Lastly: there's a SQL injection bug in your code.

Comment: is there really? id be interested in knowing where.

Comment: Nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the semicolon because that terminates the statement and the `or die` is treated as a new statement, causing the error:

```
$count=mysql_num_rows($result) or die(mysql_error());
                         //   ^ no semicolon
```

You also need parenthesis around the `die()` call.

Side note: `or die(mysql_error())` is not considered good practice because it's difficult to maintain between development and production environments. `or trigger_error(mysql_error())` would be better - this writes to your error log. Also consider upgrading to [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) because this MySQL library is deprecated and discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

#### Remove semicolon!

```
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
------------------------------^
or die mysql_error();//line 119
```

#### Change it to:

```
$count=mysql_num_rows($result) or die mysql_error();
```

It terminates!!!

#### Suggestion:

Do not use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: +1 reciprocated, don't forget it also needs `()` around the die call :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
or die mysql_error();
```

should be

```
$count=mysql_num_rows($result) or die mysql_error();
```

Any, I suggest you to avoid the use of `mysql_*` as they are being deprecated. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
or die mysql_error();//line 119
```

To this:

```
$count=mysql_num_rows($result) or die mysql_error();//line 119
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove **semicolon** and **add ()** to die in order to show it is errors & then die

```
$count=mysql_num_rows($result) or die(mysql_error()); //line 119
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't begin the line with "or"
In line 118 you end with ";"

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result) or die mysql_error();
```

But it would be better to to the error checking after result:

```
if(!$result) {
    die mysql_error();        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work. i had removed the semicolon(;) before 'or die' which caused the error..

```
$poster_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];//Posters ip
//check for ip double posting
//selecet ip from table
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE ip='$poster_ip'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result) or die mysql_error();//line 119
//if result matche posterip, table row must be 1
if($count==1){
//ip taken
echo "This IP has already submited a post. You may not submit another.";
exit();
//else script continues
}
```